# ibm data connect connection for ibm cloud object storage

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools, dataconnect

I have created bucket in ibm cloud object storage and successfully able to upload file posting there. Now, I want to refine those files using ibm data connect. I am trying to create a connection in data connect and selected bluemix object storage.
Dont understand what details  are asked  under details. Am I selecting wrong connection type or what exactly details should i look for, in my cloud object storage.

[image]

Comment: Is there a connection type for IBM Cloud Object Storage in data connect?  Bluemix Object Storage was an older version of IBM’s object storage based on the openstack swift apis.  IBM Cloud Object Storage is based on the S3 api.

Comment: No, the most matching connection I can find is bluemix cloud storage. please find snapshot for same. Is there any other way to connect both?

Comment: There is also softLayer object storage. But that i havent used.  I wish to use s3 api only , hence selected cloud object storage.

Comment: One option may be to use data refinery instead

Comment: Thanks I will try that

Answer (score 0):

Data Connect was deprecated in December 2017 and reached end-of-life 3/30/2018.  [Data Refinery](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/data-refinery) is the successor, and does [connect to IBM Cloud Object Storage natively](https://dataplatform.ibm.com/docs/content/catalog/assets-projects.html?audience=dc&context=data).  Information about migrating from Data Connect can be found [here](https://dataplatform.ibm.com/docs/content/refinery/dc_migration.html?audience=dc&context=data).